# Custom RoleProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

Estou implementando uma autenticação com `RoleProvider` Customizado.

Tenho uma classe `Usuario` e uma classe `Role` com relacionamento many to many.

Criei uma pasta no projeto chamado `Security` e dentro da pasta uma classe chamada `PermissaoProvider` que estende a classe `RoleProvider`.

O único método que subscrevi e o método abaixo:

```cs
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    var context = new RdpContext();
    var user = context.Usuarios.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Login == username);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return new string[] { };
    }

    var roles = user.Roles.Select(r => r.Nome).ToList();
    return roles.ToArray();
}
```

Criei também uma classe chamada PermissoesFiltro que segue abaixo:

```cs
public class PermissoesFiltro : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (Repositorios.UserRepositorio.GetUsuarioLogado() != null)
        {
            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/admin/Home/Negado");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/admin/login");
        }
    }
}
```

E então decoro a minha Controller da seguinte maneira:

```cs
[PermissoesFiltro(Roles = "ADM, USER")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

A Autenticação acontece normalmente, mas independente de que usuário logue e sempre redirecionado para a página de acesso negado, segue abaixo os métodos de autenticação.

```cs
public class UserRepositorio
{
    public static Usuario GetUsuarioLogado()
    {
        var usuario = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserCookieAuthentication"];

        if (usuario == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var novoToken = CryptographyRepository.Descriptografar(usuario.Value);
        int usuarioId;

        return int.TryParse(novoToken, out usuarioId) ? GetUsuarioById(usuarioId) : null;
    }

    public static Usuario GetUsuarioById(int usuarioId)
    {
        var context = new RdpContext();

        var usuario = context.Usuarios.Include("Roles").FirstOrDefault(u => u.UsuarioId == usuarioId);

        return usuario;
    }

    public static bool AutenticaUsuario(string login, string senha)
    {
        var ctx = new RdpContext();
        ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        try
        {
            var usuario = ctx.Usuarios.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Login == login && u.Status);

            if (usuario == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(usuario.Senha, senha)) return false;

            var userCookie = new HttpCookie("UserCookieAuthentication")
            {
                Value = CryptographyRepository.Criptografar(usuario.UsuarioId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
            };

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void LogOff()
    {
        var usuario = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserCookieAuthentication"];

        if (usuario == null) return;

        var userCookie = new HttpCookie("UserCookieAuthentication")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        };

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
    }
}
```

Também configurei o web.config como segue abaixo:

```xml
<roleManager defaultProvider="PermissaoProvider" enabled="true"  cacheRolesInCookie="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="PermissaoProvider" 
             type="App.Rdp.Security.PermissaoProvider" 
             connectionStringName="RdpContext"
             applicationName="/"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Estou a 2 dias pesquisando e não consigo encontrar uma solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no seu `PermissoesFiltro`: o evento `OnAuthorize` chama outro chamado `AuthorizeCore`, que efetivamente calcula a permissão. Eu faria seu override assim:

```cs
public class PermissoesFiltro : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var baseReturn = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        var permissionsReturn = false;
        /* Insira aqui sua lógica para modificar permissionsReturn para true */

        return baseReturn && permissionsReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Vou ser sincero, não entendi muito bem como fazer esta implementação, pesquisei sobre o AuthorizeCore e não conseguir entender direito como ele funciona! =/

Comment: É simples: ele devolve `true` se o usuário está autenticado e `false` em caso contrário. O que você tem que fazer é uma lógica que confira todas as etapas que você considera que o usuário precisa passar pra ser considerado autenticado pelo sistema.

Comment: O Código que postei está autenticando, na hora de autenticar ele pega o usuário com todas as suas permissões, porém ele sempre cai no método de não autorizado.

Comment: Então, mas pra considerar autenticado, tem que passar pelo `AuthorizeCore`.