# Tem como passar as roles sem usar [Authorize(Roles = "Role name")]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Meu sistema tem roles("grupos") dinamicos, o usuário que adiciona e coloca os usuários lá dentro.

Também seta que se ele pode Inserir, editar, deletar, etc...

Com uso de Asp.net Identity Roles, tem como ele fazer isso dinamicamente, sem o uso de "Role = ", ou seja, sem passar isso fixamente no controller?

Existe alguma forma? ou terei que fazer essa parte de roles do zero da forma que eu preciso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente, a ideia seria escrever seu próprio atributo de autorização. Pode ser feito sobre o ASP.NET Identity ou sobre o ASP.NET Membership.

[Há uma resposta em que eu falo sobre mais formas alternativas de autorização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21570/padr%C3%B5es-para-autoriza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-permiss%C3%A3o-de-usu%C3%A1rios/21590#21590), como a implementação de permissões por atividades. Basicamente, reimplementar permissões usando ASP.NET Identity dá mais trabalho porque são vários métodos dentro da interface que precisam ser escritos. Em compensação, as possibilidades são maiores. O Membership, apesar de ser mais simples, é um pouco mais limitado.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8808/custom-roleprovider/8809#8809) ensino a implementar um atributo simples de autorização para o ASP.NET Membership.

Comment: Hey @Cigano, a primeira opção com ASP.NET identity tb precisa passar valor fixo, caso não tem algum exemplo?

Comment: @Rod Tem vários exemplos. Veja por aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+authorize

Comment: Os exemplos são todos com custom, ao contrario da opcao 1 que você citou na resposta

Comment: Na época, eu quis dizer que você poderia usar Claims ao invés de Roles, mas me expressei muito mal. Alterei a resposta pra ficar mais objetiva.